# Is linear algebra just (boring) bookkeeping?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

As I'm learning linear algebra, it feels like there is a lot of complicated bookkeeping with matrices without much conceptual excitement.  This makes me wonder if this branch of mathematics is just a form of sophisticated bookkeeping for solving linear equations or is it a mathematics in its own right.  I would appreciate specific responses with examples that detail how linear algebra extends mathematics beyond algebra itself.  In other words, what can linear algebra do that "regular" algebra cannot?  What concepts/enlightenments are beyond the reach of algebra that are shined upon by linear algebra?

This is more of a philophical / concept question than a pedagogical question, so I pose this question here than in math education SE.

---

EDIT:  I didn't think I would need to explicitly state this, but an an explanation tailored to someone who is just starting to learn linear algebra is appreciated.

Comment: Vector spaces (one of the main building blocks of linear algebra) are critical everywhere in mathematics.

Comment: Regular algebra lets you solve individual systems of linear equations, but linear algebra gives you the tools to prove theorems about *all* linear systems as well as to model more complex mathematical objects using vector spaces and their properties. The value of the abstraction should start to become clear when your course gets into subspaces, rank & dimension, diagonalization, eigenvectors, etc.

Comment: Some example areas where Linear Algebra is vital, important and exciting(subjectively): Statistics, Physics, Computer Science - machine learning, image processing.  The list goes on and on.

Comment: I think there are many different emphasis between instructors (or textbooks). if you wanted to study more conceptual aspects but chose some computation-oriented books, you can be exhausted by the first half part of the books. these kind of books emphasize on the useful application of linear algebra for motivation. so you can choose other books concentrate on the abstract-algebraic taste. these books also deal with the same things to the computation-oriented books, but conceptual topics are discussed more faster.

Comment: I've studied arithmetic, abstract math, statistics, logic, calculus, and differential equations without linear algebra.  So no, it can't be critical/vital everywhere in mathematics.

Comment: Yeah, linear algebra as often taught for engineers is often layers upon layers of numeric techniques. It can seem tedious. But the underlying math is more than that.

Comment: @Snehal If you've looked at multivariate calculus, constant coefficient linear differential equations and/or systems of linear differential equations, or anything involving covariances, then you have used linear algebra whether you realize it or not.

Comment: @SnehalPatel A very important (and relatively accessible) example of applications of linear algebra to engineering is the mathematics of Fourier series

Comment: @SnehalPatel can't get very far into statistics without having linear algebra. How are you going to manipulate data in any meaningful manner without making use of linear algebra?   Without linear algebra, the computer/phone/tablet you are using to get on this website wouldn't be able to exist.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article on Linear algebra yet?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I was thinking exactly about the examples you gave (multivariable calculus, etc.).  Isn't that just making the point that linear algebra is really just bookkeeping?

Comment: @SnehalPatel The **application** of linear algebra (e.g. the careful application of the multivariate chain rule) is very often a matter of "bookkeeping", as you say. The *theory* of linear algebra (for instance, **why** the chain rule is the natural way that derivatives "combine" under composition) can be beautiful and a powerful tool for insight.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, that is a great explanation and example.  Thanks!

Comment: @Snehal Another noteworthy example from calculus is the generalization of the second derivative test to multivariate functions, that is the way you classify critical points of a graph $z = f(x,y)$ using the second-order partial derivatives. **Why** does the test work the way it does? How should that test generalize for "graphs" $z = f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$? All of that comes out of the study of bilinear forms, an area of linear algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using matrices to solve simultaneous linear equations does seem like fairly boring bookkeeping (although there are practical advantages to using matrices to represent and solve linear equations in computer programs). But this is just the tip of the iceberg. One of the most important properties of matrices is that matrix multiplication is not commutative - indeed, matrices are, in some sense, the prototypical non-commutative objects in mathematics. This allows us to use matrices to represent:

- linear geometric transformations and their associated symmetries
- elements in non-commutative groups - in fact, you can think of the whole of group theory as a spin-off of linear algebra, although it is not usually taught that way
- linear operations on functions, such as differentiation
- operations on qubits in quantum computing
- graphs and networks in [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)
- elements of non-commutative number systems such as [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

and many other things. And I haven't even mentioned infinite matrices and [Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) ...

Answer (score 0):

The theory of vector spaces over a field is a structure that fits the axiomatics of a category.

There, you should consider how the objects (vector spaces) are related among them, that is, there are maps of certain kinds called linear transformations.

Comment: I don't think that inviting categories in the debate can be enlightning for somebody asking for "an explanation tailored to someone who is just starting to learn linear algebra"

Comment: however this is cultivating a long sight on modern ideas